# How to manage HorizontalTextAlignment of TextBlock in lower versions?

Tags: uwp-xaml

When I try to use HorizontalTextAlignment in Textblock text's content alignment to align it's text to center, (We can see the effect only when text is multiline), it warns me with "Not available in this min version", it needs 'Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (introduced v10.0.16299.0)'

I want to know what workaround could be done to handle this. I tried with multiple textblocks in a stackpanel, but seems not an efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to manage HorizontalTextAlignment of TextBlock in lower versions?

Please check [TextBlock.HorizontalTextAlignment Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.horizontaltextalignment#remarks) remarks part.

> This property provides the same functionality as the [**`TextAlignment`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.textalignment) property. If both properties are set to conflicting values, the last one set is used.
>
> Apps that target the Fall Creators Update (SDK 16299) or later should use this property instead of TextAlignment. If your app also supports previous versions

You use `TextAlignment` property in lower version.